# how to start into the x window server from linux mint ?

Tags: command-line, x11, xorg

what do i have to do in the terminal in order to switch all the frontends of the xserver off, just to have the x window system running without any window manager or desktop environment?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but you can try to boot your machine into single user mode, and just run "startx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should kill your Display Manager to switch all frontends of the xserver off. It could be:

```
mdm - MATE Display Manager
gdm - Gnome Display Manager
kdm - KDE Display Manager
xdm - X Window Display Manager
```

The corresponding one should be killed. E.g:

```
sudo killall mdm
```

To start a plain xserver you should type this command:

```
sudo X
```

More info [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/X.7.html).

After that, for example you could start an xterm on it:

```
xterm -geometry +1+1 -n login -display :0
```